# Cannot stop search bar from showing cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I'm trying to stop the cancel button from appearing when I click on a search bar. I've tried this -

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton: NO animated:NO];
NSLog(@"CANCEL BUTTON : %hhd", self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsCancelButton);
```

and the log tells me the `showsCancelButton` has a value of `0`, indicating it's off.

So what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the cancel button to hide, in the "searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch" delegate method, like:

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    controller.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

and you can also use below if you don't use UISearchDisplayController

```
-(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    //This'll Show The cancelButton with Animation
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: than make sure you have set delegate to self.

Comment: @praks5432: have you check ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    - (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
        return YES;
    }
```